# How to delete old files from document directory in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdocumentdirectory

I would like to delete old files (15 days or older) from the user's `~documents` directory in objective-c. Is there a way to know when a file was created and subsequently delete them?

Comment: I would like a pizza. Is there a question somewhere?

Comment: And you want to develop an application in Objective-C for that?

Comment: Sorry i just need a function to delete old files (camera captures) from my application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't completely understand your question, but I'm going to assume you want a way for a Mac application to identify old files and delete them. If so, try this:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSArray *files = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/samplePath/" error:NULL];

for (NSString *path in files) {
    BOOL isDir;
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDir] && !isDir) {
        NSDictionary *attr = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:NULL];
        NSDate *modDate = [attr objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate];
        //Do date math
    }
}
```

That will get a date for each date in a directory (just substitute the string `@"/samplePath"` with an actual path). Then, you can do the date math to find how long ago it was modified. Alternatively, you could replace `NSFileModificationDate` with `NSFileCreationDate` to get when the files were created.